# Selecting and averaging values in pandas data frames

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas, data-analysis

I am new to the [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) data analysis library. The task I need to get done is the following:

Given a data frame (table) with a set of columns `C`, select all the rows for which the values in a subset of columns `A` are identical and combine them to a single row in which the values for the other rows `C \ A` are averaged.

(The goal is to test multiple runs of an program and average the values like running time in those cases where the parameters are identical.)

For example:

```
a       b       c       d
eggs    ham     1.0     0.0
eggs    ham     0.0     0.5
spam    eggs    0.0     1.0
spam    eggs    0.0     1.0
```

should be combined to:

```
a       b       c       d
eggs    ham     0.5     0.25
spam    eggs    0.0     1.0
```

when selecting the columns `a` and `b` (which means that `c` and `d` should be averaged).

What are my options?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what groupby does

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html

```
from StringIO import StringIO

txt = """a       b       c       d
eggs    ham     1.0     0.0
eggs    ham     0.0     0.5
spam    eggs    0.0     1.0
spam    eggs    0.0     1.0"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), sep="\\s+")
df.groupby(["a","b"], as_index=False).mean()
```